# Nautilus: Settings schema 'org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files' is not installed

Tags: gnome, dependencies, nautilus, clear-linux

I've installed the Gnome desktop and Nautilus on Clear Linux using a custom mix (without the `desktop` bundle), and have encountered the following error in the terminal when starting Nautilus:

```
(org.gnome.Nautilus:6833): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 23:30:55.621: Settings schema 'org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files' is not installed
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Nautilus will not start with `nautilus` or through the Files app. This seems like a dependencies issue as installing the `desktop-apps` bundle fixes it.

What causes this issue, and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to install `gnome-photos`. When I removed that package on ClearLinux I used to get the same error. After installing the bundle everything was okay.

Comment: Thanks! I had exact same issue on ClearLinux.